# Can we create a matrix with neighbouring columns?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

Suppose that I have the matrix:

```
df=
       a  b  c  d  e 
    z  1  1  1  0  1  
    y  0  0  0  1  0
    x  1  0  1  0  0
    w  0  1  0  0  1
    v  0  0  0  1  0
```

Now we want to find all neigbouring columns and put that in a matrix. For my example this gives the result:

```
result = 
       a  b  c  d  e 
    a  1  1  1  0  1  
    b  1  1  1  0  1
    c  1  1  1  0  1
    d  0  0  0  0  0
    e  1  1  1  0  0
```

Logic is as follows: since a and b columns both have a 1 in row z there should be 1 in the cell a,b and b,a. One mutual row is sufficient.

Now I am doing it with a for-loop but it is too slow.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [[1,  1,  1,  0,  1], 
                    [0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
                    [1,  0,  1,  0,  0],
                    [0,  1,  0,  0,  1],
                    [0,  0,  0,  1,  0]],
                    index=['a',  'b',  'c',  'd', 'e' ],
                    columns=['a',  'b',  'c',  'd', 'e' ],
                     )
result = pd.DataFrame(False, index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)
for row in result.index:
    my_rows = df.index[df.loc[:, row]]
    my_neighbours = df.columns[df.loc[my_rows, :].any(axis=0)]
    result.loc[row, my_neighbours] = True
```

Does anyone have an alternative?

Comment: "since a and b columns both have a 1 in row x" --> but they don't have in your example

Comment: sorry my mistake, should have been z excuse me

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite get the logic. Can you show us the foo loop to produce the result?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( [[1,  1,  1,  0,  1], 
                    [0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
                    [1,  0,  1,  0,  0],
                    [0,  1,  0,  0,  1],
                    [0,  0,  0,  1,  0]],
                    index=['a',  'b',  'c',  'd', 'e' ],
                    columns=['a',  'b',  'c',  'd', 'e' ],
                     )

res = pd.DataFrame( index= ['a',  'b',  'c',  'd', 'e' ])

for col in df.columns:
    res[col] = df.apply( lambda row:  int(row[col]==1 and row[row.name]==1), axis=1 )
```

But as mentioned in comments, notice that you have an error in your example output.
Also I had to guess what you want in some default cases.

```
res
Out[176]: 
   a  b  c  d  e
a  1  1  1  0  1
b  0  0  0  0  0
c  1  0  1  0  0
d  0  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  0  0  0
```

It is also possible, to achieve the result with inliner below:

```
res2 = df.apply( lambda row:  pd.Series([int(row[col]==1 and row[row.name]==1) for col in row.index], index=row.index), axis=1, result_type='expand' )
```